# multipathd checker failed

Tags: linux, centos, multipath-storage

There are 2 LUNs from different storage (HITACHI, HP MSA 2040) to my server (HP DL380 G9).
and I 'JUST' got this error every day on my LUN that presented from HP storage and on my same PATH (Just on 65:48):

```
kernel: device-mapper: multipath: Failing path 65:48  
multipathd: mpathf: sdt - directio checker reports path is down  
multipathd: checker failed path 65:48 in map mpathf  
multipathd: mpathf: remaining active paths: 3  
kernel: qla2xxx [0000:0b:00.1]-801c:2: Abort command issued nexus=2:4:0 --  1 2002.  
/usr/sbin/rsct/sapolicies/db2/hadrV105_monitor.ksh: Entering : db2inst1 db2inst1 LOGDB972   
/usr/sbin/rsct/sapolicies/db2/hadrV105_monitor.ksh: Entering : db2inst1 db2inst1 LOGDB981  
hadrV105_monitor.ksh[88596]: Returning 2 : db2inst1 db2inst1 LOGDB972  
hadrV105_monitor.ksh[88609]: Returning 2 : db2inst1 db2inst1 LOGDB981  
multipathd: mpathf: sdt - directio checker reports path is up  "
```

My *multipath.conf* file is configured as below:

```
  blacklist {
   devnode "^sda"  
  }
```

At the end I should say I changed all of my connection (Fiber Cable, storage HBA and server HBA). And there isn't any error on my storage console.
Could be error due to the my operating system (CentOS 6.9)?

Comment: Any tool doing backup at this time ?

Comment: @Archemar, No, I give the error in different time on the same PATH.